# Angular 7 ng build, registry.registerUriHandler is not a function in bitbucket pipelines

Tags: javascript, angular, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines, angular7

I just updated my app to Angular 7, it compiles fine in local but when i try to deploy to bitbucket i get this error with ng build

> registry.registerUriHandler is not a function TypeError:
>   registry.registerUriHandler is not a function
>       at Object.runCommand (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:47:14)
>       at default_1 (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js:32:54)
>       at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js:125:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)

I don't understand what has pipelines to do with this but i think it could be an error with angular, any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure you're only running `ng build` for your deploy? You (should) be running something like `ng build --prod --aot` If you try to run a prod build with aot, can you reproduce it locally?

Comment: I'm using ng build --configuration=test to build with a custom enviroment, but i have been using that for a while and i can make the build locally with no problems

Comment: What is in your test configuration?

Comment: Only this... "test": { "fileReplacements": [ { "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts", "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts" } ] }

Comment: Do you have a repo you can share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i found the problem after lots of headaches, pipelines was trying to build the angular 7 app with the angular 6 cli, even thought i was explicitly installing @angular/cli 7.0.2. I discovered that pipelines makes a cache of node_modules so it was using the old cli, cleaning the cache made the error go away.